# Java: multidimensional arrays - which dimension goes first?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

is there any performance difference between these two arrays in java (may be relevant for J2ME development...):

```
String[][][] a = //for getting an entry by a[group][person][field]
    {
        { // group A:
            {"John", "Doe", "teacher", "New York"},
            {"Donald", "Duck", "jinx", "Duckburg"},
            // 10 or more further entries
        },
        { // group B:
            {"Barack", "Obama", "president", "Washington"},
            // ...
        }
    };
String[][][] b = //for getting an entry by b[field][group][person]
    {
        { // prenames:
            {"John", "Donald", ...},
            {"Barack", ...}
        },
        { // surnames:
            {"Doe", "Duck", ...},
            {"Obama", ...}
        },
        { // job:
            {"teacher", "jinx", ...},
            {"president", ...}
        },
        { // city:
            {"New York", "Duckburg", ...},
            {"Washington", ...}
        }
    };
```

I would guess the second array is more performant because it consinsts of less nested arrays in total, while the first array has one array for each person! transfering this on bigger arrays...

Thanks for your answers!

**UPDATE:**

A better (realistic) example is an array of, let's say, 1000 x/y-coordinates:

```
int[][] coordsA =
    {
        {0, 0},
        {2, 7},
        {8, 2},
        {4, 2},
        {-3, 15},
        {1, 32},
        // ...
    };
int[][] coordsB =
    {
        {0, 2, 8, 4, -3, 1, ...}, // x values
        {0, 7, 2, 2, 15, 32, ...} // y values
    }
```

Comment: How are there fewer arrays? Your variable declaration kind of defines how many there are. In any case, any reason you're not using classes for this? It's what they're for.

Comment: See also [The historical collection classes—Arrays](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-arrays/).

Comment: A multi-dimensional array does not mean that its elements are nested you can always directly access its attributes, e.g. `a[1][2][3]`. Thus, in this case performance is a function of your access pattern...

Comment: I would say that fewer arrays might save you the memory taken by some `length` fields and pointers, but I'm not sure it would make much of a difference. I agree with @home about the access pattern though, due to caching. You can take a look at [this](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/threadspotter/docs/2011.1/manual/ch05s02.html), though I'm not entirely sure how it applies to Java on a mobile device.

Comment: @flo: if you really want to use array for what you need to do and want the best perfs on J2ME (as you wrote in your question) then *the* trick for J2ME used to consist in flattening out the array (of course this means potentially having empty cells) and doing the "array index arithmetic" yourself, saving on the array bound checks (only one such check would be done instead of three in your case).  Nowadays it's unlikely such tricks would offer measurable performances gain but it used to be big on these old clunky J2ME cellphones : )

Comment: well, I would intuitively say that without paying attention to the number of Objects in total, each nested array needs kind of "head" memory - so it might be more memory efficient if you have less of these nested arrays... But I thought there is someone who has a deeper knowledge of the JRE ;-) btw. this question is not really a problem but rather a theoretical thing that interests me... thanks tho

Comment: added a better example code snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<insert usual knuth quote, etc. here - but I assume anyone here knows that already anyhow>`

The problem with Java is that each array level is regarded as one object itself, i.e. we don't get continuous memory regions for our array (well the GC could help a bit there)

This has several effects:

- worse cache locality
- additional bounds checks for each array level
- additional memory accesses necessary to access one element

Not very nice that (i.e. in the worst case instead of having one memory access for one element, we may get 2*index level memory accesses), so the usual solution if you need efficient arrays is to create only one large array and do the indexing yourself. That avoids all these problems at the cost of needing some simple helper methods (which are pretty simple especially if all sub arrays have the same size).

**But** the performance gains also largely depend on your access scheme. If you want to compare the two different variants given in your post it probably won't matter that much (i.e. nowhere near the same gains you get in C or co if you order your arrays correctly). Accessing them sequentially in their sub arrays should still give better cache locality though.

Answer (score 3):

Years ago, when I was using Fortran, we were told to arrange our loops on multi-dimensional arrays so that the first dimension was the one that iterated fastest because of the way that the memory was arranged, and it would cause fewer page faults.

However, since then, I've learnt that in Java (as in almost everything), if you *have* a performance problem, you should **measure** all of the proposed solutions until you find a solution in which you no longer have the performance issue. Premature optimisation is the root of all evil etc.

If you think that the number of arrays will be a problem, have you measured the amount of memory that each option takes? Have you measured the time taken for particular operations.

If you don't have a performance problem, then use the representation that fits your requirements the best.

Comment: The reason you were told to arrange the loops that way was because fortran uses [column-major ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) instead of the today more usual row-major ordering of c-like languages and if you do it the other way around you get horrible cache locality. But then since java doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays that doesn't make much difference here.

Comment: @Voo I know. But the point was when you're doing performance, measure it.

Comment: Yeah we all know that quote by heart (although I always find it entertaining that it comes from the guy who thought that C was way too inefficient), but still no reason to chose the less performant solution if it's exactly the same effort and complexity. Accessing something as `arr[i][j]` instead of `arr[j][i]` is hardly problematic and will give vast improvements in the right language.